# Time-series: Using decomposed components (seasonality+trend) as covariates in multiple regression?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, seasonality, trend, predictor

I need to evaluate the effects of a treatment on a time-series data-set by comparing multiple dependent variables to a prior time period without treatment in effect. I'm using a python library to extract seasonality, trend and residual, and I plan to use the seasonality and trend as variables in a multiple regression analysis. There are multiple dependent variables that I'm trying to measure, such as product margin, sales, average order value, etc. This is E-commerce data.

Questions:

1) The treatment period lasted 25 days. Dataset is composed of 4 years of data (at the day level). When controlling for seasonality and trend, should I base the trend and seasonality off of a 25 day period (because that's how long the treatment was in effect), or should they be calculated using the complete 4 years of data, while holding out the treatment dates?

2) One of the dependent variables I'm looking at is product margin, this is stationary according to Dicky-Fuller test. Does this mean that I should not include trend in the model and only include seasonality?

3) I'm having difficulty determining the frequency of seasonality and trend. For example, my data is daily, so I can view seasonality based on a 7 day pattern or trend based on the 7 day rolling avg in order to control for weekly fluctuations in the dependent variable. Similarly, I can extend this to 30 days for monthly fluctuations, 90 days for quarterly, 365 for yearly etc. The extracted seasonality and trend will be used as additional predictors in the model to isolate the treatment effects. I just don't know how to decide this frequency.